# What is the name/type/species of this spider?

Tags: species-identification

Below are images of it, specimen found in the western region of the Pacific Northwest - North America.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I presume it is ***Eratigena atrica***, commonly called the giant house spider.

It belongs to      Agelenidae family.

> E. atrica is found in Europe, Central Asia and Northern Africa. It was unwittingly introduced to the **Pacific Northwest of North America** circa 1900 due to human activity and has strongly **increased in numbers** for the last century.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_house_spider)

Comment: This is, indeed, a giant house spider. But the species known to be established in the Pacific Northwest is Eratigena duellica, not E.atrica. (E.duellica is still part of the "E.atrica complex")